# Cost function of exponent loop?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

How do you calculate the cost function for this loop:

```
    for (int i=3; i^2<N; i=i+2) {
        // One operation here
}
```

Along with the cost function, what is the Big-O notation?

Comment: Try starting by guessing w/ some small examples at the cost function. ie, for `N = 4` how many iterations would you expect. What about `N = 9`, or `N = 16`?

Answer (score 1):

The number of iterations is determined by the loop condition, which is `i^2<N`. The loop start with 3 and is increased by 2 in each iteration. The condition of the loop ensures that the loop will run until `i^2` becomes equal to or greater than `N`. The value of `i^2` increases linearly as `i` increases, which means that the value of `i^2` will increase faster than `i`. As a result, the value of `i^2` will reach N much faster than `i` will reach N. Finally, the loop will run ⌊√n⌋ iterations, which means that the time complexity is O(sqrt(n)).